# ReactFlow make background image pan with the canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the ReactFlow library. At the moment if I add a background to my ReactFlow background like so:

```
<Background
          color='#fff'
          gap={16}
          style = { { backgroundImage: 'url(myImage.png)'}}
/>
```

The background stays fixed while i pan the canvas. Is it possible to make the background image move with the panning of the canvas? I couldn't seem to find anything to allow this on the docs

Example image bellow:

Before panning:
[image]

After panning to the right:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding what's happening.
Your image *is* panning with the background that's why it's changed it's position in the first place.
Your *nodes* are the ones that stay in place and don't move (unless you move them of course, like dragging them).

If you want to use an image as if it were a node, then use a custom node.
[Here's an example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-dijkstra-fn0xhk?file=/src/CustomNode.tsx)

Using an image to cover the whole background would be a bit tricky and would require a custom background solution that probably just repeats the image on the canvas. But I don't quite see what the purpose of that would be.